# npm install bootstrap-material-datepicker

Tags: momentjs, npm-install, bootstrap-datetimepicker, react-rails, bootstrap-material-design

I'm working with React and Rails and implementing material design in my app. I'm loading the modules using webpack. I have been able to get bootstrap-material-design and moment.js through npm but now, i want to integrate [bootstrap material datepicker](https://github.com/T00rk/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker) but i'm unable to use it as i cannot find a way to install it using npm. If a put a offline file in my client/app/javascripts folder and registers it in the webpack, i find the moment not defined error.

If a add a moment.js file in the folder as well, i get ./locale missing error. And when i put the locale folder provided by moment, i get the path error thati'm unable to reso;ve. I can across a similar issue but couldn't find a dsolution.

Thank you for any help. Please let me know if anymore information is required.

P.S.: I cannot include all of these in the assets of rails.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install it with Bower according to it's docs.

> bower install bootstrap-material-datetimepicker

If you don't have bower installed, you can install it with npm:

> npm install -g bower

Comment: Hey. I'm a stranger to `Bower`. Where do i install it? inside the root folder or the client or inside the node modules? Also, i did install the bootstrap material datepicker using the bower but i cant figure out how to load them or are they loaded automatically? I'm using Weback to load other modules. I'm still getting the `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).bootstrapMaterialDatePicker is not a function`

Comment: You can install bower globally with npm with that command above. The - g tells npm to install it globally. 

After running the command, you shield be able to type 'bower'  in your command line

Comment: I'm able to install it and used it to install the `bootstrap-material-datetimepicker` as well. But do i have to load these files somewhere or they get loaded automatically. Because, I keep getting the `undefined (...).bootstrapMaterialDatePicker() is not a function`.

Comment: Can you upload the file which is using bootstrap-material-datetimepicker?  Maybe I need a little more context :)

Comment: No Worries. I'll update the code. Actually i switched to jquery.timepicker. It had already consumed my lot of time and i'm on time limit here.